# Try to run an NLP model with an Electra instead of a BERT model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I want to run the [wl-coref](https://github.com/vdobrovolskii/wl-coref) model with an Electra model instead of a Bert model. However, I get an error message with the Electra model and can't find a hint in the Huggingface documentation on how to fix it.

I try different BERT models such like roberta-base, bert-base-german-cased or SpanBERT/spanbert-base-cased. All works.
But if I try an Electra model, like google/electra-base-discriminator or german-nlp-group/electra-base-german-uncased then it doesn't work.

The error that is displayed:

```
out, _ = self.bert(subwords_batches_tensor,  attention_mask=torch.tensor(attention_mask, device=self.config.device))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

And this is the method where the error comes from:[_bertify](https://github.com/vdobrovolskii/wl-coref/blob/master/coref/coref_model.py#L332) in line 349.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the underscore `_`. [ELECTRA](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/electra#transformers.ElectraModel.forward) does not return a pooling output like [BERT](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel.forward) or [RoBerta](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/roberta#transformers.RobertaModel.forward):

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

def bla(model_id:str):
  t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
  m = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_id)

  print(m(**t("this is a test", return_tensors="pt")).keys())

bla("google/electra-base-discriminator")
bla("roberta-base")
```

Output:

```
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state'])
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output'])
```